# HtmlBox JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, web-scripting

I'm using the HtmlBox 2.8 (http://remiya.com/cms/projects/jquery-plugins/htmlbox/) 
Turns the textarea to a richtext editor.

when i change the value of the textarea, `$('#Survey_Value').val(data.Value);`
the text in the richeditor does not change.

how to change the text the text in the rich text editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HtmlBox has a `set_text(html)` method you can call.  Store the original htmlbox call you have now:

```
var box = $('#Survey_Value').htmlbox();
```

When you have new data call this:

```
box.set_text(data.Value);
```

This method accepts html and will set your `<textarea>`'s value as well.

Comment: i tried it but it only addeds a new rich text editor(that has new value) in the existing rich editor

Comment: @CoffeeCode - Wasn't aware it wouldn't detect this, updated the answer, this approach should work, let me know if it gives other trouble.